# Good start for .Net and c++ to Java transition?

Tags: java, .net, c++

I know the .Net framework very well and know where to find things ie: StreamReader, StreamWriter, Graphics, etc, and I know Java has similar things. The syntax is different but quite similar to c++ which I have a lot of native c++ experience. Therefore, what would you recomend as a good starting point for tutorials and such. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my new job, I quickly found myself working on a common library in C++, C# and Java. I had no Java knowledge and yet found it pretty intuitive to make simple mods to the Java code - the general C# principle that there is a framework class/namespace for most things you want to do, appear to hold in Java.

The thing that bothers me is that this MO would not teach me tricks and improvements in Java that are specific to that language.  That's where I would like to see other answers to this question lead.

In the meantime: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java

btw while I found C# and Java pretty congruent, I would not say the same about C++ vs Java.

Comment: Definitely +1 to that. C# and Java are vastly more similar than C++ and Java.

Comment: C# was derived primarily from Java (Actually from J++ which was their rename of Java after sun said they couldn't use the Java name for their "embrace and extend" practice.  It should be much more like Java than either is like C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in eclipse/netbeans/intelliJ it may actually be a no-brainer.  Guess at a class name, start typing it and hit ctrl-space (for eclipse, others vary).  Regardless of which package it is in, it will find all the classes that match and list them for you faster than you could look them up anywhere else.

The other really nice thing to have on hand is the javadocs for the SDK you are working with--you can code effectively with nothing else.  They are online (just search for JDK 6.0 or whatever version) or they can be downloaded from the same place you get the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

The javadocs are your friend - once you figure out some of the main packages in java.*, it's easier to know where to look for specific classes / functionality.

Once you're writing some code, buy Effective Java - it's full of tips for the language, and is just a good programming book.